# Looking for a meaningful interpretation to Numbers 23:10 - "Who counted the dust of Jacob or the number of a fourth of Israel?"

Tags: parashat-balak, bilam

Would anyone be able to explain (or link me to) a meaningful interpretation to Numbers 23:10 - "Who counted the dust of Jacob or the number of a fourth of Israel?"

- Why the comparison to dust?
- Why the 2 names of Jacob and Israel?
- What is the idea of "a fourth of Israel?"

Comment: What do you mean by "a meaningful interpretation"?

Answer (score 1):

Rashi on [Balak 23:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9951/showrashi/true#v10)

> Who counted the dust of Jacob or the number of a fourth of [or, of the
> seed of] Israel? May my soul die the death of the upright and let my
> end be like his."

explains

> **Who can count the dust of Jacob:** As the Targum [Onkelos] renders, “the children of the house of Jacob, [concerning whom it was stated,
> 'they shall be as many as the dust of the earth, or one] of the four
> camps” - [referring to] the four divisions. Another interpretation:
> The dust of Jacob-The number of mitzvoth they fulfill with dust are
> innumerable: “You shall not plow with an ox and a donkey [together]”
> (Deut. 22:10);“You shall not sow your field with a mixture of seeds”
> (Lev. 19:19), the ashes of the red cow (19:19), the dust used for a
> woman suspected of infidelity, and others similar to these. — [Mid.
> Tanchuma Balak 12, Num. Rabbah 20:19]
>
> **or the number of the seed of:** [The word רֹבַע denotes] their copulations; the seed which issues from sexual intercourse. — [Mid.
> Tanchuma Balak 12, Num. Rabbah 20:19]

Rav Hirsch translates this pasuk as

> Who then counts the dust of Jacob and the number of purely physical
> animal-like births of Israel.

Rav Hirsch explains that this means that someone who attempts to consider the strength of a people by the sheer physical numbers is completely mistaken. The term *Jacob* means the people on a physical level. The term *Israel* means on the level that allowed Jacob to have his name changed to *Israel* by reaching the higher spiritual level. In either case, Bil'am is stating that any one who regards the *strength* of Bnai Yisrael on a physical level, so that he thinks that all that needs to be done is reduce that physical level, does not understand what is going on.

> מי מנה עפר יעקוב וגו, You, Balak count the numerical size of this
> people (CH. XXII,5 I.L.), the number of its fighters, by that
> reckoning it seems too big for you, and you believe that if one could
> reduce it in that direction you would be able to conquer it, you
> believe that if one altogether one could get at it vially if one could
> succeed in bringing a curse on its material bodily thriving: מי מנה
> עפר יעקוב, who then counts what is earthly in Jacob, ומספר את רבע
> ישראל, and counts the physically born numbers of Israel (- רבע in the
> sam sense as in Lev. XIX,19 & XX,16 -). The prestige of other nwations
> may rest on the number of the "bodies" of its population, their
> increasse may form a threat to be feared by other nations, their
> decrease give rise to hopes. Not so is itwith Jacob-Israel. Whether
> they are small in numbers as "Jacob" or growing numerous as "Israel",
> it is not that which is עפר and which increases or diminishes itself
> just by animal-like breeding in which its importance, its happiness or
> unhapiness consists. Not even death have they to fear, bodily deathe
> cannot reach their true selves תמות נפשי וגו. I would like to die as
> they do, to know that my end would be like theirs, their dying is more
> blissful than our living, because they are ישרים, because they
> correspond to the calling for which on the whole men are "men" and
> strive for this purpose in a "straight line" without turning aside.
> Summarising this first "parable" of Balaam, he had thereby to point
> out to Balak the complete specific difference of Israel to all the
> other nations, and to tell him that the future of this nation was
> completely independent of the physical-material causes which could be
> assumed to be the conditions for the growth and development of other
> nations. Hence they would also be unreachable by all damaging
> influences to which the welfare of other nations could be made to
> succumb. But as his words made the judging of the well-being of this
> nation altogether depended on the principles out of which it made its
> prosperity, this speech is a true משל, one that goes beyond the
> concrete single case, a sying which brings a fact, a moral, applicable
> generally out of the actual example quoted.